# Difference between desktop and server virtualization?

Tags: virtualization, desktop

I have read many article but, still difference between them confusing.
Server virualization virualizes the physical server while desktop virtualization virtualizates desktop.

Can somebody elaborate with example?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this is about

- a powerful piece of hardware able to run **many** more instances of "something"
- virtualization technology that supports "slicing" that single hardware instance into those "somethings"

And from there: such a "something" can either be an instance of a *service*; or it can make up what you, as a user perceive as "desktop".

In that sense, your distinction doesn't really exist: desktop virtualization is nothing else but a **server** offering "client desktops" to its users; instead of say a http or database service.